# Замена "\" на "/" Python

Tags: python, ос

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: мне нужно открыть определённый `.exe` файл. Для этого я его ищу с помощью функции `os.system("where /R C:\ programm.exe")`, эта функция возвращает пути в виде `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\programm.exe`. С помощью функции `os.startfile(path)` я хочу открыть файл, НО данная функция принимает путь в котором присутствует `/` либо `\\`. Как можно заменить данные символы?

Буду рад помощи!

```
def open():
    prog= os.system("where /R C:\ programm.exe")
    os.startfile("C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\programm.exe")
```

Comment: Заменить - с помощью `prog = prog.replace('\', '/')`, но вообще вы можете просто использовать raw-строки: `r'C:\path\to\file' == 'C:\\path\\\to\\file'`.

Comment: @andreymal, нет, данная функция читает только```/```, а в получаемом пути присутствуют ```\```

Comment: @EzikBro, пробовал, но не вышло

Comment: Смотрите, `os.startfile` работать точно будет, если применить `replace` к строке, которая там сейчас находится. На самом деле, скорее всего, "не работает" (как вы ожидаете) `os.system`.  Дело в том, что при выполнении данной функции она возвращает код возврата, а не текстовый вывод консоли. Если вы выведете значение `prog`, то там будет 0 или 1, а не список путей. Чтобы получить этот вывод, используйте `os.popen` или `subprocess.Popen`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879